# Duplicate Symbols with IOS Build

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run my Flutter app on IOS (on Android it works properly), but I'm getting the following error when I try to run it:

```
 Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro Max in debug mode...
Xcode build done.                                           13,6s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_GULZeroingWeakContainer._object' in:
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULAppDelegateSwizzler 2.o
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULAppDelegateSwizzler.o
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_GULAppDelegateObserver' in:
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULAppDelegateSwizzler 2.o
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULAppDelegateSwizzler.o
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GULAppDelegateObserver' in:
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULAppDelegateSwizzler 2.o
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULAppDelegateSwizzler.o
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_GULZeroingWeakContainer' in:
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULAppDelegateSwizzler 2.o
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULAppDelegateSwizzler.o
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GULZeroingWeakContainer' in:
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULAppDelegateSwizzler 2.o
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULAppDelegateSwizzler.o
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_GULAppDelegateSwizzler' in:
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULAppDelegateSwizzler 2.o
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULAppDelegateSwizzler.o
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GULAppDelegateSwizzler' in:
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULAppDelegateSwizzler 2.o
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULAppDelegateSwizzler.o
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_GULAppDelegateObserver._isObserving' in:
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULAppDelegateSwizzler 2.o
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULAppDelegateSwizzler.o
    duplicate symbol '_GULLogError' in:
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULLogger 2.o
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULLogger.o
    duplicate symbol '_kGULNetworkTempDirectoryName' in:
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULNetworkConstants 2.o
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULNetworkConstants.o
    duplicate symbol '_kGULNetworkHTTPStatusCodeUnavailable' in:
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULNetworkConstants 2.o
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULNetworkConstants.o
    duplicate symbol '_kGULNetworkHTTPStatusCodeNotFound' in:
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULNetworkConstants 2.o
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULNetworkConstants.o
    duplicate symbol '_kGULNetworkHTTPStatusCodeFound' in:
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULNetworkConstants 2.o
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULNetworkConstants.o
    duplicate symbol '_kGULNetworkHTTPStatusCodeNotModified' in:
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULNetworkConstants 2.o
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULNetworkConstants.o
    duplicate symbol '_kGULNetworkHTTPStatusCodeCannotAcceptTraffic' in:
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULNetworkConstants 2.o
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULNetworkConstants.o
    duplicate symbol '_kGULNetworkHTTPStatusOK' in:
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULNetworkConstants 2.o
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULNetworkConstants.o
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_GULNetworkURLSession._request' in:
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULNetworkURLSession 2.o
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULNetworkURLSession.o
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_GULNetworkURLSession._completionHandler' in:
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULNetworkURLSession 2.o
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULNetworkURLSession.o
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_GULNetworkURLSession' in:
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULNetworkURLSession 2.o
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULNetworkURLSession.o
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GULNetworkURLSession' in:
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULNetworkURLSession 2.o
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULNetworkURLSession.o
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_GULNetworkURLSession._URLSession' in:
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULNetworkURLSession 2.o
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULNetworkURLSession.o
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_GULNetworkURLSession._sessionConfig' in:
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULNetworkURLSession 2.o
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULNetworkURLSession.o
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_GULNetworkURLSession._loggerDelegate' in:
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULNetworkURLSession 2.o
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULNetworkURLSession.o
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_GULNetworkURLSession._backgroundNetworkEnabled' in:
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULNetworkURLSession 2.o
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULNetworkURLSession.o
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_GULNetworkURLSession._downloadedData' in:
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULNetworkURLSession 2.o
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULNetworkURLSession.o
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_GULNetworkURLSession._networkDirectoryURL' in:
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULNetworkURLSession 2.o
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULNetworkURLSession.o
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_GULNetworkURLSession._uploadingFileURL' in:
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULNetworkURLSession 2.o
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULNetworkURLSession.o
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_GULNetworkURLSession._sessionID' in:
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULNetworkURLSession 2.o
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULNetworkURLSession.o
    duplicate symbol '_GULNSDataZlibRemainingBytesKey' in:
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULNSData+zlib 2.o
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULNSData+zlib.o
    duplicate symbol '_GULNSDataZlibErrorKey' in:
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULNSData+zlib 2.o
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULNSData+zlib.o
    duplicate symbol '_GULNSDataZlibErrorDomain' in:
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULNSData+zlib 2.o
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULNSData+zlib.o
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_GULReachabilityChecker' in:
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULReachabilityChecker 2.o
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULReachabilityChecker.o
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GULReachabilityChecker' in:
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULReachabilityChecker 2.o
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULReachabilityChecker.o
    duplicate symbol '_GULReachabilityStatusString' in:
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULReachabilityChecker 2.o
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULReachabilityChecker.o
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_GULReachabilityChecker.reachability_' in:
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULReachabilityChecker 2.o
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULReachabilityChecker.o
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_GULReachabilityChecker.host_' in:
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULReachabilityChecker 2.o
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GULReachabilityChecker.o
    ld: 91 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    duplicate symbol '_pb_field_iter_next' in:
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/pb_common 3.o
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/pb_common.o
    duplicate symbol '_pb_field_iter_begin' in:
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/pb_common 3.o
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/pb_common.o
    duplicate symbol '_pb_field_iter_find' in:
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/pb_common 3.o
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/pb_common.o
    duplicate symbol '_pb_decode_svarint' in:
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/pb_decode 3.o
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/pb_decode.o
    duplicate symbol '_pb_decode_varint' in:
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/pb_decode 3.o
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/pb_decode.o
    duplicate symbol '_pb_decode_noinit' in:
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/pb_decode 3.o
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/pb_decode.o
    duplicate symbol '_pb_decode_delimited_noinit' in:
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/pb_decode 3.o
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/pb_decode.o
    duplicate symbol '_pb_istream_from_buffer' in:
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/pb_decode 3.o
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/pb_decode.o
    duplicate symbol '_pb_close_string_substream' in:
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/pb_decode 3.o
        /Users/youni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bdpblnudevgtxmfuhxwqrsfeiwpe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/pb_decode.o
    ld: 34 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    note: Using new build systemnote: Planning buildnote: Constructing build descriptionwarning: Mapping architecture armv7 to i386. Ensure that this target's Architectures and Valid Architectures build settings are configured correctly for the iOS Simulator platform. (in target 'image_picker' from project 'Pods')warning: Mapping architecture arm64 to x86_64. Ensure that this target's Architectures and Valid Architectures build settings are configured correctly for the iOS Simulator platform. (in target 'image_picker' from project 'Pods')
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Target Platform: IOS
Target OS version/browser: 9.0
Devices: Iphone 11 Pro Max

With the command Flutter analyze the issues found are only some unused import or variables.
flutter doctor -v:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.5, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G103, locale it-IT)
    • Flutter version 1.9.1+hotfix.5 at /Users/youni/Desktop/YoUni/flutter
    • Framework revision 1aedbb1835 (4 weeks ago), 2019-10-17 08:37:27 -0700
    • Engine revision b863200c37
    • Dart version 2.5.0

[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, set ANDROID_HOME to that location.
      You may also want to add it to your PATH environment variable.


[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.0)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.0, Build version 11A420a
    • CocoaPods version 1.6.0

[!] Android Studio (version 3.4)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.39.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.6.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • iPhone 11 Pro Max • AC410C15-8848-486F-B911-2826D9BCD39F • ios • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-0 (simulator)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

I upgraded the image_picker plugin to the latest version and the first time the app run properly, the second time it gives me this error. So I don't understand if the error is caused by this plugin or by something else. Tell me if I have missed or you need some additional informations.
Ps. I had to delete some lines of the Xcode's output because of the characters limits, if you need the complete log tell me please.

Comment: when i get those strange things, sometimes executing "flutter clean" helps. Just in case you didnt try that yet.

Answer (score 26):

This can happen when project is inside an iCloud directory, causing file duplication. There are two workarounds I see:

1- Remove duplicate files from root project. **Always run find command without -delete first to make sure you're not deleting unwanted files**

```
find . -name \*\ 2.\*
find . -name \*\ 2.\* -delete
find . -name \*\ 3.\*
find . -name \*\ 3.\* -delete
flutter clean
flutter run
```

2- Clean/reinstall pods, with the commands below (on flutter project root)

```
cd ios
pod deintegrate
cd ..
flutter clean
flutter run
```

The final solution would be removing flutter project from iCloud directory. However I also use it inside an iCloud directory, in order to make sure my "gitignored" files are backed-up. I'm also seeking for a better solution.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Great answer, it fixed so well on me!

Answer (score 4):

This happens sometime when `flutter package get` doesn't complete or fall into a deadlock due to connectivity issues or something similar.

The following command will perform a temporal fix.

```
  cd ios/
  pod cache clean --all
  pod deintegrate --verbose
  pod setup --verbose
  pod install --verbose
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me - for the target that reports warnings, change the "Valid Architecture" setting to:

```
$(VALID_ARCHS)
x86_64
```

Could you also try changing Deployment target to, for instance, 13.2? I hope this helps

Comment: I'm sorry but for me didn't work. I also tried to delete DeriveData folder and run flutter clean but nothing works. Thanks for your answer by the way.

Comment: As IOS Deployment Target the maximum version is 13.0 but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked for me until I found that I had a flutter/.pub-cache directory that contained multiple copies of files, which apparently get copied to ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ each time.

After I deleted the .pub-cache directory and all existing DerivedData directories, my builds started working again.

My development folder is on iCloud, maybe that has something to do with why this started. Weirdly enough the .pub-cache directory did not (yet) come back, will need to keep my eyes open for it.