# Flutter duplicate symbol "_FLTPathProviderPlugin" problem

Tags: ios, flutter

Error when building flutter project...

- macOS BigSur, Dart 2.13.0
- Testing on both macOS iPhone simulator and my own device(iPhon 11 pro)

Here is console output

```
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_FLTPathProviderPlugin' in:

    /Users/***/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-caugwmsivvbynqfcckyjmhducipk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/path_provider.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FLTPathProviderPlugin 2.o

    /Users/***/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-caugwmsivvbynqfcckyjmhducipk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/path_provider.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FLTPathProviderPlugin.o
```

I don't even know it is correct that same plugin(FLTPathProviderPlugin.o, 2.o)is generated at the same time.

Randomly FlutterKeyboardVisibilityPlugin.o(+ 2.o) generated too(also duplicates error)

I tried

- pub clean
- flutter clean
- delete under the ~/Xcode/DerivedData/ directory (It gets re-generated every time)
- delete .pub-cache

I just moved my whole project fold out of /Users/Desktop, which is not related to iCloud and my flutter SDK too.(cause I heard that this could be a iCloud problem)

When I made a new flutter project, it works and successfully build on iPhone simulator.

But after added some dependencies in pubspec.yaml(get pubsepc too), same error is occurred.
Is there any chances that plugin dependency crashes can cause this problem?

Here is my dependencies :

```
    sqflite: ^1.1.6
    path_provider: ^1.2.0
    path: ^1.6.2
    table_calendar: ^2.3.3 
    flutter_datetime_picker: ^1.5.0 
    flutter_typeahead: ^2.0.0
    flutter_swiper: ^1.1.6
    async: ^2.3.0
    syncfusion_flutter_charts: ^18.4.46
    fl_chart: ^0.20.1
    charts_flutter: ^0.10.0
    flutter_masked_text: ^0.7.0
    http: ^0.12.0+2
```

This flutter actually worked well but literally suddenly get failed... I'm so desperate..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Duplicate Symbols with IOS Build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58905933/duplicate-symbols-with-ios-build)

Comment: Thanks but I also read that article, and I tried.. but failed 

Comment: See [ask] to improve this question.

Comment: solved by reinstall the flutter SDK. I hope you do not waste your time to reinstall Xcode (It took so long...) cause it's not helpful.