# Error (Xcode): 460 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 MACos

Tags: flutter, macos

hi every one I'm working on creating an app with flutter may device is Macbooc pro M1 and the simulator is not working for me because this error appears to me and I really don't know how to solve it

the error is
Error (Xcode): 460 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

it is appears on the terminal of VS code .

please help me

Comment: [Duplicate Symbols with IOS Build](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58905933/10157127) may help

Answer (score 0):

I think its `Flutter create .` (after updating flutter maybe some new files have to be created? idk) and I used [enter link description here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons)
but for the images you had to make a Check in the Checkbox "Alpha". So I included... `flutter_icons: android: true ios: true remove_alpha_ios: true //...this line image_path: "lib/assets/icon/xxx"`

this works specific for this package.